# Delphi - launching multiple threads, and combining their output

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I am not new to Delphi, but new to using threads. I am working on a project that needs to query several servers for data, and I thought I would try implementing it using threads. The idea is to create a dedicated thread to send and process a query to each remote server, and then use the main program to combine and process the collected data returned from the threads.
I found several examples that show how to launch multiple threads, and they seem to all do it using "for" loop. I implemented the same method in my project but was disappointed to see that this method still waits for each thread to finish before launching the next one. I would like to be able to launch all the threads at the same time, and wait for them to collect the requested data and return it, then process it.  What would be the recommended way to do this?
Here is the simplified code, illustrating the "not running simultaneously" problem:

```
unit threads2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, support, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;


  TMyThread = Class(TThread)
  private
     fnumber : longint;
     fLog:tstrings;
     fExecutionTime:TDateTime;
     fiLimit: longint;
  public
     constructor Create(createsuspended: boolean; iLimit:integer);
     procedure Execute(); override;
  end;


var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TMyThread.Create(createsuspended: boolean; ilimit:longint);
begin
  inherited Create(createsuspended);
  self.fLog := tstringlist.Create;
  self.fiLimit := ilimit;
  self.fExecutionTime := 0;
  self.execute;
end;



procedure Tmythread.Execute;
var i,rcode:longint;
begin
  self.fExecutionTime := now;
  self.flog.Add(AddDotsAndLeftJ(35,'.','Started thread '+inttostr(self.threadID)+' at ')+': ' + formatdatetime('h:nn:ss:zzz', now()));
  self.flog.Add(AddDotsAndLeftJ(35,'.','Limit: ')+': ' + inttostr(self.filimit));

  self.fnumber := 0;
  for I := 0 to self.fiLimit do
  begin
    self.fnumber:=self.fnumber + random(5);
  end;

  self.fExecutionTime := now()-self.fExecutionTime;
  self.flog.Add(AddDotsAndLeftJ(35,'.','Sum: ')+': ' + inttostr(self.fnumber));
  self.flog.Add(AddDotsAndLeftJ(35,'.','Finished thread '+inttostr(self.threadID)+' at ')+': ' + formatdatetime('h:nn:ss:zzz', now()));
  self.flog.Add(AddDotsAndLeftJ(35,'.','Thread execution time')+': ' + formatdatetime('h:nn:ss:zzz', self.fExecutionTime));
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var n,i:longint;
    mt:tmythread;
    s:string;
begin
  for i := 0 to 5 do
  begin

    case i of
    0: n:=100000;
    1: n:=1000000;
    2: n:=10000000;
    3: n:=100000000;
    4: n:=10000000;
    5: n:=1000000000;
    end;


    mt:=TMyThread.Create(true,n);

    memo1.Lines.AddStrings(mt.fLog);
    memo1.Lines.Add('------------------------------------');

  end;
end;


end.
```

---

The output looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGKlC.png)

The start and end times of each thread suggests that the threads are running strictly sequentially; the next thread always starts after the previous one finished

---

---

The second part of my question has to do with how the threads are managed, and how to collect the output of the returning threads.  I created a dynamic array and setlength it to the number of the threads I am about to launch. Each element of the array is a record (threadDataRecord) that will be used to store the output of the associated thread. Each thread has a local variable that matches the structure of that data record, and it fills that variable while it's executing. Once the thread is finished, it copies the contents of the local record into the array element associated with the thread (i.e. Thread #4 will copy its data into the record at array[4] ).
It does seem to work as intended, but the question is, is it safe to do so? While the array is a shared variable, no thread is writing to the same array element at the same time; if I have each thread write to a separate array element, is this a thread-safe way of accessing/modifying the array?

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!  Thank you

Comment: We need to see your code

Comment: From your description it sounds fine. If only thread #4 writes to element 4 in the array, you should be okay.

Comment: You didn't show the important code. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: It's also confusing that you create 1 + threadcount threads. Did you mean to do that?

Comment: "*this method still waits for each thread to finish before launching the next one*" - no it does not. If your app is exhibiting that behavior then you are doing something wrong, but we can't see what you are really doing. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I added the simplified code into the original question.

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using? If you are using newer Delphi versions using Parallel programming library and tasks might be better approach than creating threads directly.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I am using Delphi 11 community edition

Comment: @500-InternalServerError at first glance it looked like my code updated the individual array elements from each dedicated thread, but it only worked because I did not code the threads correctly - the threads were not actually created and were all executed from the main program. I am now able to launch the threads correctly (they all start at the same time in parallel, as originally intended) but now I am having trouble modifying those array elements from the threads.

Comment: In that case you can use [Parallel Programming Library](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Using_the_Parallel_Programming_Library) You can also find some code examples at https://github.com/dalijap/code-delphi-thread-safety and https://github.com/dalijap/code-delphi-async

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You should never manually call your threads Execute method!**

And that is exactly your problem. Since you are calling your thread `Execute` method from within constructor it is executed by your application main thread the same as constructor was.

---

I see you are creating your threads in suspended state. If you do so then you also needs to make sure to start the said thread. You do this by calling [TThread.Start](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Classes.TThread.Start) after the creation of the thread.

```
mt:=TMyThread.Create(true,n);
mt.Start;
```

This then automatically executes code within threads `Execute` method. And it will be executed by the said thread unless you are making use of [Synchronize](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) somewhere within that code. That would force code within Synchronize call to be executed on main thread.

---

EDIT: Here is an example of using multithreading for processing some data. The example uses OnTerminate event to notify the main thread when execution of specific worker thread has finished. Example also implements custom notification event that can be used for notifying of current work progress for each thread (optional).

I'm also providing detailed in code comments in order to provide better understanding of how this code works.

I'm using a different data structure but I'm sure you will be able to adapt this to your needs.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Math, System.DateUtils, System.TimeSpan;

type
  //Enumeration type for representing internal thread state
  //This can be usefull to makr different stages of thread processing
  TInternalThreadState = (Start, RandomSumation, RandomSubstraction, Finish);

  //Class for stroing work data
  TWorkData = class(TObject)
    //Initial data prepared before work is assigned to any thead
    NumberOfCalculations: Integer;
    WorkNo: Integer;
    //Return data filled by the thread the work was assigned for
    startTime: TDateTime;
    endTime: TDateTime;
    ThreadID: Integer;
    Log: TStringList;
  public
    //We use constructor for creating additional internal objects like Log at creation of work class
    constructor Create;
    //Using destructor we free up all internal created objects on destruction of the work class itself
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  //Definition for special procedure type that we will use as progress notification event method
  TThreadProgressNotification = procedure(Sender: TObject; PercentageDone: Integer; WorkState: TInternalThreadState) of object;

  //Type deffinition of custom thread class
  TMyWorkerThread = class(TThread)
  private
    //Field stroing reference to progress event notification method
    fOnProgress: TThreadProgressNotification;
    //Reference to WorkData
    fWorkData: TWorkData;
    //Index at which thread is stored in thread list
    fThreadIndex: Integer;
    //Internal string list that we use for storing thread log
    fThreadLog: TStringList;
    //Custon internal thread state that we can use to mark specific stages of thread processing
    fThreadInternalState: TInternalThreadState;
    //Number of calculation that this threads was assigned to perform
    fNumberOfCalculations: Integer;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    //Method that will be fired when the thread finishes its execution
    //We use this method to notify main thead that worker thread has finished its work
    //and also return any processed data
    procedure OnTerminateEvent(Sender: TObject);
  public
    //Custom constructor for our woorker thread that allows passing some additional parameters
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; ThreadIndex: Integer; ThreadData: TWorkData);
    //Destructor that we wil use for cleaing up ouw worker thread data
    destructor Destroy; override;
    //Property with which we can optionaly assing event method for reporting current thread progress
    property OnProgress: TThreadProgressNotification read fOnProgress write fOnProgress;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    //Actual event method for reporting worker thread progress
    procedure OnThreadProgress(Sender: TObject; PercentageDone: Integer; WorkState: TInternalThreadState);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  //Array holding work data
  ArrWorkdata: Array of TWorkData;
  //Array of worker threads
  ArrThreads: Array of TMyWorkerThread;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TMyThread }

constructor TMyWorkerThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; ThreadIndex: Integer; ThreadData: TWorkData);
begin
  //Call inherited constructor of the base TThread class passing value of CreateSuspended argument
  //Since we are using custom constructor format we need to manually specify the format of base class constructor
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  //We set FreeOnTerminate to false in order to prevent thread of automaticaly freing its data after finishing work
  FreeOnTerminate := False;
  //Assigning work data reference to our work tread.
  fWorkData := ThreadData;
  //Assigning index at which thread is stored in our thread list
  fThreadIndex := ThreadIndex;
  //Setting initial internal thread state
  fThreadInternalState := TInternalThreadState.Start;
  //Setting hte number of calculation that this thread will work on
  fNumberOfcalculations := fWorkData.NumberOfcalculations;
  //Creating the internal thread log
  fThreadLog := TStringList.Create;
  //Writing first entry into thread log marking its start
  fThreadLog.Add('ThreadNo: '+IntToStr(fThreadIndex)+' ThreadID: '+IntToStr(self.ThreadID)+' Thread started at: '+DateTimeToStr(now));
  //Log the start of work in linked WorkData
  self.fWorkData.startTime := Now;
end;

destructor TMyWorkerThread.Destroy;
begin
  //Free the internal thread log upon thread destruction
  fThreadLog.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyWorkerThread.Execute;
var I: Integer;
    N: Int64;
    PercentageDone: Integer;
begin
  //Random sumation - internal stage of work thread
  fThreadInternalState := TInternalThreadState.RandomSumation;
  //Log start of work stage
  fThreadLog.Add('ThreadNo: '+IntToStr(fThreadIndex)+' ThreadID: '+IntToStr(self.ThreadID)+' Random sumation started at: '+DateTimeToStr(now));
  //Do some work
  for I := 0 to fNumberOfCalculations do
  begin
    //After processing every N number of items we report progress to the main thread if
    //OnProgress event method has been assigned
    //We do this using Synchronize that forces the code to be executed on main thread
    //This allows us to safely acces any UI elements
    //We should not fire this to often or we will overlaod main thread
    if (I>0) and  ((I mod 100000) = 0) then
    begin
      Synchronize(procedure
      begin
        //Check if OnProgress event method has been asigned
        if Assigned(OnProgress) then
        begin
          //Calculate percentage of the work done on current work stage
          PercentageDone := Round(I / fNumberOfCalculations *100);
          //Call OnProgress event method passing relevant parameters
          OnProgress(Self,PercentageDone,Self.fThreadInternalState);
        end;
      end)
    end;
    N := N+Random(1000);
  end;
  //Log end of work stage
  fThreadLog.Add('ThreadNo: '+IntToStr(fThreadIndex)+' ThreadID: '+IntToStr(self.ThreadID)+' Random sumation finished at: '+DateTimeToStr(now));

  //Random substraction
  fThreadInternalState := TInternalThreadState.RandomSubstraction;
  fThreadLog.Add('ThreadNo: '+IntToStr(fThreadIndex)+' ThreadID: '+IntToStr(self.ThreadID)+' Random substraction started at: '+DateTimeToStr(now));
  for I := 0 to fNumberOfCalculations do
  begin
    if (I>0) and  ((I mod 100000) = 0) then
    begin
      Synchronize(procedure
      begin
        if Assigned(OnProgress) then
        begin
          PercentageDone := Round(I / fNumberOfCalculations *100);
          OnProgress(Self,PercentageDone,Self.fThreadInternalState);
        end;
      end)
    end;
    N := N-Random(1000);
  end;
  fThreadLog.Add('ThreadNo: '+IntToStr(fThreadIndex)+' ThreadID: '+IntToStr(self.ThreadID)+' Random substraction finished at: '+DateTimeToStr(now));
  fThreadInternalState := TInternalThreadState.Finish;
  //Log entire work done
  fThreadLog.Add('ThreadNo: '+IntToStr(fThreadIndex)+' ThreadID: '+IntToStr(self.ThreadID)+' Thread finished at: '+DateTimeToStr(now));
end;

procedure TMyWorkerThread.OnTerminateEvent(Sender: TObject);
var ElapsedTime: Int64;
begin
  //Log the end of work in linked WorkData
  self.fWorkData.endTime := Now;
  //Notify main thread that work thread has been destroyed
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('ThreadNo: '+IntToStr(fThreadIndex)+' ThreadID: '+IntToStr(self.ThreadID)+' Thread finished at: '+DateTimeToStr(now));
  ElapsedTime := System.DateUtils.MilliSecondsBetween(self.fWorkData.startTime,self.fWorkData.endTime);
  //Notify of how long thread execution was
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('ThreadNo: '+IntToStr(fThreadIndex)+' ThreadID: '+IntToStr(self.ThreadID)+' Thread finished in: '+IntToStr(ElapsedTime)+' ms');
  //Log thread destruction in linked WorkData
  self.fWorkData.Log.AddStrings(self.fThreadLog);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var I: Integer;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  Memo2.Lines.Clear;
  //Create the Workdata classes
  for I := 0 to Length(ArrWorkdata)-1 do
  begin
    ArrWorkdata[I] := TWorkData.Create;
    ArrWorkdata[I].WorkNo := I;
    //Assign randon number of calculations from within specific ragne that represent this work
    //Thisis done to represent different workloads
    ArrWorkdata[I].NumberOfCalculations := RandomRange(1000000,10000000);
  end;
  //Create our worker threads
  for I := 0 to Length(arrThreads)-1 do
  begin
    arrThreads[I] := TMyWorkerThread.Create(True,I,ArrWorkdata[I]);
    //Assign reference to event method that will be used  to notify of thread termination and
    //can also preform some data transfer from thread to WorkObject
    arrThreads[I].OnTerminate := arrThreads[I].OnTerminateEvent;
    //Optionally assing OnProgres event method that will be used to notify the main thread about
    //current progres of specifc thread
    arrThreads[I].OnProgress := OnThreadProgress;
    Memo2.Lines.Add('ThreadNo: '+IntToStr(I)+' ThreadID: '+IntToStr(arrThreads[I].ThreadID)+' Thread started at: '+DateTimeToStr(now));
    //Start the woorker thread
    arrThreads[I].Start;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //We need to call Randomize at least once before using any random function
  Randomize;
  SetLength(ArrWorkdata,8);
  SetLength(ArrThreads,8);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
var I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to Length(ArrWorkdata)-1 do
  begin
    ArrWorkdata[I].Free;
  end;
  for I := 0 to Length(ArrThreads)-1 do
  begin
    ArrThreads[I].Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.OnThreadProgress(Sender: TObject; PercentageDone: Integer; WorkState: TInternalThreadState);
begin
  //Visualy prepresent work progress as log
  Memo1.Lines.Add('ThreadNo: '+IntToStr(TMyWorkerThread(Sender).fThreadIndex)+' ThreadID: '+IntToStr(TMyWorkerThread(Sender).ThreadID)+' Work state'+IntToStr(Ord(WorkState))+' Work done: '+IntToStr(PercentageDone));
  //Visualy represent progress of specific thread
  Memo2.Lines[TMyWorkerThread(Sender).fThreadIndex] := 'ThreadNo: '+IntToStr(TMyWorkerThread(Sender).fThreadIndex)+' ThreadID: '+IntToStr(TMyWorkerThread(Sender).ThreadID)+' Work state'+IntToStr(Ord(WorkState))+' Work done: '+IntToStr(PercentageDone);
end;

{ TThreadData }

constructor TWorkData.Create;
begin
  //Create a string list that will store log for this WorkData
  self.Log := TStringList.Create;
end;

destructor TWorkData.Destroy;
begin
  //Free the WorkData log
  self.Log.Free;
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

Comment: This indeed was the problem; I removed the ".execute" statement from ".create" section and added the line to start the thread manually inside the "for" loop and I can see that the threads are now starting at the same time.

Comment: I have another issue now. I am having a problem passing data between the thread and the main program. I pass a data record to my thread as follows:
constructor TMyThread.Create(createsuspended: boolean; ilimit:longint; var ThreadData: TThreadDataRec);
I can see that the data is being modified inside "execute" code (ThreadData contains a Tstrings log and I can save it to file while inside the "execute" code") but that data never makes it out of the thread once the code is finished. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that you are passing the same variable to each thread. Therefore all of your threads are are in a race condition for writing to the same variable which will lead to data corruption. There is [TThread.OnTerminate](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Classes.TThread.OnTerminate) that fires once the thread has finished its execution. You can write code for passing data from thread to your main application here. This event is executed within the main thread so you can safely access UI items from it. ...

Comment: .. Just make sure to minimize the amount of code here otherwise you may overload your main thread and thus get slow performance.

Comment: SilverWarior -  thank you for the TThread.OnTerminate suggestion - I tried it but probably did not do it right as it did not do what I wanted. 
And thank you for catching "passing the same variable to each thread" - a genuine bug where I was initializing the threads wrong. I fixed it and everything worked fine after.

Comment: @Vlad I have written an example that is making use of OnTerminate event and also defines additional custom even that can be optionally used for reporting progress during longer thread execution. As you can see I have commented it in detail in order to allow you to better understand what is going on. I hope this might help you further.

Comment: You may also want to check [Parallel Programming with OmniThreadLibrary - the book is here!](https://www.thedelphigeek.com/2018/02/parallel-programming-with.html). While the mentioned book focuses mainly on using very powerful OmniThreadLibrary that was designed by the book author himself the first few chapter of the book explains basics of how multi-threading works and thus can be great source of knowledge even if you don't decide to use OmniThreadLibrary itself.

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to everyone who responded. This is my first attempt at using threads for my apps, and it was a bit challenging as I have not used threads before.
I had an idea of using threads to collect data from remote servers in parallel as opposed to one after another as I normally do, so I put together this test project. The idea is to maintain an array of data records that each thread would fill with the information obtained from the target servers. A timer would check all threads to see if they are finished running, and when they are, it would process the results.  The working code below is my first working prototype for the benefit of anyone on the same path as me, at the same stage of Delphi learning. All comments and improvement suggestions are welcome!
This example illustrates setting up the desired number of threads, and exchanging data between the threads and the main program. Note that while the threads are writing to the same variable in the main program, that variable is an array and each thread is only writing to the array element associated with it, so no two threads are writing to the same array element - this avoids collisions.
Also this example does not actually talk to remote servers, it just sums a bunch random numbers - the payload is not important for this exercise.

```
unit threads2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, support, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;


type TThreadDataRec = packed record
    strThreadName : string;
    tsLog: Tstrings;
    dtExecutionTime:TDateTime;
    intThreadID: integer;
    number:longint;
    boolFinished: boolean;
    fLimit:longint;
    Idx:integer;  // contains the index of the array element, is needed to link it to the actual thread
    threadp: pointer;
end;
type TThreadDataArray = array of TThreadDataRec;

  TMyThread = Class(TThread)
  private
     fThreadData: TThreadDataRec;
     fRecIndex:integer;   // contains the index of this thread's record in main ThreadDataArray
     fDone:boolean;
  public
     constructor Create(createsuspended: boolean; ilimit:longint; fidx: integer);
     procedure Execute(); override;
  end;
  TMyThreads = array of TMyThread;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    ThreadDataArray: TThreadDataArray;  // holds the data returned from threads after the threads are terminated
    MyThreads: TMyThreads;  // array of threads while they are alive
    ThreadCount: integer;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  var offset:integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TMyThread.Create(createsuspended: boolean; ilimit:longint; fidx: integer);
begin
  inherited Create(createsuspended);

  // init the local thread data record
  with self.fThreadData do
  begin
    if not assigned(self.fThreadData.tsLog) then
       self.fThreadData.tsLog := TstringList.Create;
    strThreadName:= 'thread_'+inttostr(self.ThreadID);
    intThreadID := self.ThreadID;
    dtExecutionTime := 0;
    boolFinished := false;
    fLimit := ilimit;
    Idx := fidx;  // links the array data element
  end;

  self.fDone := false;
  self.fRecIndex := fidx; // links the array data element
end;


procedure Tmythread.Execute();
var i,rcode:longint;
begin

  with self.fThreadData do
  begin
    strThreadName := 'thread_'+inttostr(self.ThreadID);
    tsLog.Add(AddDotsAndLeftJ(offset,'.','Thread: ')+': ' + strThreadName);
    dtExecutionTime := now;
    if not assigned( tsLog) then
       tsLog := tstringlist.Create;
    tsLog.Add(AddDotsAndLeftJ(offset,'.','Started thread '+inttostr(self.threadID)+' at ')+': ' + formatdatetime('h:nn:ss:zzz', now()));
    tsLog.Add(AddDotsAndLeftJ(offset,'.','Limit: ')+': ' + inttostr(fLimit));
    number := 0;
    for I := 0 to fLimit do
    begin
      number:= number + random(5);
    end;

    dtExecutionTime := now()- dtExecutionTime;

    tsLog.Add(AddDotsAndLeftJ(offset,'.','Sum: ')+': ' + inttostr(number));
    tsLog.Add(AddDotsAndLeftJ(offset,'.','Finished thread '+inttostr(self.threadID)+' at ')+': ' + formatdatetime('h:nn:ss:zzz', now()));
    tsLog.Add(AddDotsAndLeftJ(offset,'.','Thread execution time')+': ' + formatdatetime('h:nn:ss:zzz', dtExecutionTime));
    tsLog.Add(AddDotsAndLeftJ(offset,'.','Local Flag value BEFORE')+': ' + booltostr(boolFinished));
    boolFinished := true;
    tsLog.Add(AddDotsAndLeftJ(offset,'.','Local Flag value AFTER')+': ' + booltostr(boolFinished));

    tsLog.Add(AddDotsAndLeftJ(offset,'.','Name read from main array at idx ['+inttostr(self.fRecIndex)+'] BEFORE')+': ' +
                                                                                form1.ThreadDataArray[self.fRecIndex].strThreadName);

    form1.ThreadDataArray[self.fRecIndex].strThreadName := self.fThreadData.strThreadName;

    tsLog.Add(AddDotsAndLeftJ(offset,'.','Name written to main array at idx ['+inttostr(self.fRecIndex)+'] AFTER')+': ' +
                                                                                form1.ThreadDataArray[self.fRecIndex].strThreadName);

    tsLog.Add(AddDotsAndLeftJ(offset,'.','Flag read from mythread array BEFORE: ')+': ' +
                                                                                booltostr( form1.mythreads[self.fRecIndex].fDone));
    form1.mythreads[self.fRecIndex].fDone := true;
    tsLog.Add(AddDotsAndLeftJ(offset,'.','Flag Written to mythread array AFTER: ')+': ' +
                                                                                booltostr( form1.mythreads[self.fRecIndex].fDone));

    form1.ThreadDataArray[self.fRecIndex].tsLog.AddStrings(tsLog);
    tsLog.SaveToFile('c:\temp\threaddata_thread_'+inttostr(self.ThreadID)+'.txt');
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var n,i:longint;
    mt:tmythread;
    s:string;
begin
  for i := 0 to ThreadCount-1 do
  begin

    case i of
    0: n:=100000;
    1: n:=1000000;
    2: n:=10000000;
    3: n:=100000000;
    4: n:=10000000;
    5: n:=1000000000;
    else
      n:=99999999;
    end;

    // mt:=
    form1.MyThreads[i]:= TMyThread.Create(true, n, i); //, form1.ThreadArray[i]);
    form1.ThreadDataArray[i].threadp:= form1.MyThreads[i];
    form1.MyThreads[i].start;

  end;

  timer1.Interval := 100;
  timer1.Enabled := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  timer1.Enabled := false;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i:integer;
begin
  ThreadCount := 10;
  offset := 50;
  panel2.Align := alclient;
  memo1.Align := alclient;
  Setlength(form1.ThreadDataArray,ThreadCount);
  SetLength(form1.MyThreads, ThreadCount);
  for i := 0 to ThreadCount-1 do
  begin
    form1.ThreadDataArray[i].tsLog := tstringlist.Create;
    form1.ThreadDataArray[i].boolFinished := false;
    form1.ThreadDataArray[i].strThreadName := 'no name';
    form1.ThreadDataArray[i].dtExecutionTime := 0;
    form1.ThreadDataArray[i].intThreadID := 0;
    form1.ThreadDataArray[i].number := 0;
    form1.ThreadDataArray[i].fLimit := 0;
    form1.ThreadDataArray[i].Idx := 0;
  end;
  timer1.Enabled := false;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var i, donecount:integer;
begin
   memo1.Lines.Add('timer firing');
   memo1.Lines.Add('------------------------------------');
   donecount := 0;

   // check every thread's "done" flag to see if the thread is finished
   // this can be done differently; one can check "Finished" 
   // property of each thread instead
   for I := 0 to ThreadCount-1 do
   begin
     memo1.Lines.Add('Thread: '+form1.MyThreads[i].fThreadData.strThreadName);
     memo1.Lines.Add('Sum: '+inttostr(form1.MyThreads[i].fThreadData.number));
     memo1.Lines.Add('- Done? '+booltostr(form1.MyThreads[i].fThreadData.boolFinished));
     if form1.MyThreads[i].fThreadData.boolFinished=true then
         inc(donecount);
   end;
   memo1.lines.Add(' - Done count: '+inttostr(donecount));

   // if NOT all threads are finished, then exit, else proceed to work on the retrieved data
   if donecount <> ThreadCount then exit;

   // stop the timer
   timer1.Enabled := false;

   // process the data that was created/retrieved by the threads; in this example, print each
   // thread's logs in the main Memo1
   for I := 0 to ThreadCount-1 do
   begin
     memo1.Lines.Add(' ');
     memo1.Lines.Add('log from thread: '+form1.MyThreads[i].fThreadData.strThreadName);
     memo1.Lines.AddStrings(form1.MyThreads[i].fThreadData.tsLog);
     memo1.Lines.Add('====================================');
   end;
end;

end.
```